# How to use PHP Router with Awebserver Mobile Application

Tags: php, router

Have been trying to find out the Problem why it's not working when I try to redirect to the index Page from the .htaccess file. It keeps bringing out the default 404 Page if the link file does not exist.

**.htaccess File**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 

    echo "Welcome";

?>
```

Both files are in the same root of the project directory.

It suppose to show the index page in any link they goes.

That's the Problem. If you have any solution to that. Please help.

Comment: What are you using for a web server? Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely happening because you have AllowOverride None configured for your Apache server. To fix this, you'll need to enable the .htaccess overrides.

To do this, edit your Apache configuration (e.g. httpd.conf) and change:

AllowOverride None

To:

AllowOverride All

Then restart Apache for the changes to take effect.

This will allow .htaccess files to override the server configuration and enable your rewrite rules.

After that, your .htaccess file should work as expected and redirect all requests to index.php.

Comment: Wow. I found the configs file and edited it. Now working bro. Thanks 